# Getting RunTimeError while using mmsegmentation

Tags: python, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am using mmsegmentation to segment a custom dataset. I have made my own config for it. I am getting error that essentially says every tensor that I am providing is not of the same size.

I checked all the image sizes in my dataset. They are equal. I am getting the following error.

I am facing trouble in finding out the exact statement in the program that is raising the error hence I do not know how to solve it.

```
 File "tools/train.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 100, in main
    runner.train()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1721, in train
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 278, in run
    self.run_iter(data_batch)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 301, in run_iter
    outputs = self.runner.model.train_step(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 121, in train_step
    losses = self._run_forward(data, mode='loss')
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 161, in _run_forward
    results = self(**data, mode=mode)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1040, in forward
    output = self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1000, in _run_ddp_forward
    return module_to_run(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/base.py", line 94, in forward
    return self.loss(inputs, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 176, in loss
    loss_decode = self._decode_head_forward_train(x, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 137, in _decode_head_forward_train
    loss_decode = self.decode_head.loss(inputs, data_samples,
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 262, in loss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 104, in <module>
    losses = self.loss_by_feat(seg_logits, batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 305, in loss_by_feat
    seg_label = self._stack_batch_gt(batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 289, in _stack_batch_gt
    return torch.stack(gt_semantic_segs, dim=0)
    main()RuntimeError
: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [421, 604, 516] at entry 0 and [512, 513, 516] at entry 1  File "tools/train.py", line 100, in main

    runner.train()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1721, in train
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 278, in run
    self.run_iter(data_batch)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 301, in run_iter
    outputs = self.runner.model.train_step(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 121, in train_step
    losses = self._run_forward(data, mode='loss')
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 161, in _run_forward
    results = self(**data, mode=mode)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1040, in forward
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 100, in main
    runner.train()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1721, in train
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 278, in run
    self.run_iter(data_batch)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 301, in run_iter
    outputs = self.runner.model.train_step(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 121, in train_step
    losses = self._run_forward(data, mode='loss')
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 161, in _run_forward
    results = self(**data, mode=mode)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1040, in forward
    output = self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1000, in _run_ddp_forward
    return module_to_run(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/base.py", line 94, in forward
    return self.loss(inputs, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 176, in loss
    loss_decode = self._decode_head_forward_train(x, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 137, in _decode_head_forward_train
    loss_decode = self.decode_head.loss(inputs, data_samples,
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 262, in loss
    losses = self.loss_by_feat(seg_logits, batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 305, in loss_by_feat
    seg_label = self._stack_batch_gt(batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 289, in _stack_batch_gt
    return torch.stack(gt_semantic_segs, dim=0)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [512, 513, 516] at entry 0 and [236, 789, 516] at entry 1
    output = self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1000, in _run_ddp_forward
    return module_to_run(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/base.py", line 94, in forward
    return self.loss(inputs, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 176, in loss
    loss_decode = self._decode_head_forward_train(x, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 137, in _decode_head_forward_train
    loss_decode = self.decode_head.loss(inputs, data_samples,
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 262, in loss
    losses = self.loss_by_feat(seg_logits, batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 305, in loss_by_feat
    seg_label = self._stack_batch_gt(batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 289, in _stack_batch_gt
    return torch.stack(gt_semantic_segs, dim=0)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [284, 741, 516] at entry 0 and [205, 820, 516] at entry 1
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 1820710) of binary: /home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 195, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 191, in main
    launch(args)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 176, in launch
    run(args)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 753, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 132, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 246, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
```

Comment: It's showing you the sizes it's complaining about.  Obviously, your inputs are NOT all the same size.

Comment: I have checked every image size manually. On top of that I created a script to do the same. It also shows all sizes are equal. And I have been using same dataset for other deep learning models and never received this error. 

So trust me when I say, all images in my dataset are of same size.

Comment: Are you processing them in different ways?  Is `(421,604,516)` a familiar size?

Comment: I am aware that this is not exactly a regular tensor size. But the thing is mmsegmentation repo provides its own script for data loader and training. And that is the reason why I am not able to pin point the origin of the error message.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "regular" tensor size, but the fact that it's telling you exactly what it doesn't like should give you a thread to pull on.  You'll have to put debug prints in the segmentation to find where it goes awry.

Comment: Ok. I will try to do that. But since the program accepts some  command line arguments. So I have avoided to put breakpoints

Comment: your traceback appears to be garbled. multiple different tracebacks randomly interleaved. is there any multithreading or multiprocessing going on? if so, see about disabling that. helps with reading the traceback(s)

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz you are right, I am training on multiple GPUs. I will try to disable that and check if the error is more understandable.